# Razor views vs partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

how does visual studio determine which is a view vs a partial view? Another question would be; is there a way to convert my views into partial views?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Razor there is no distinction between views and partial views as there is in WebForms (.aspx vs .ascx). In Razor all views are templates. Those templates could have a Layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

In this case they are views. If there is no layout specified they could be considered as partial views. The Layout is usually defined in the `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file.

This being said if from your controller action you `return PartialView();` instead of `return View();` this layout will not be applied.

I would recommend you reading the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/22/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts.aspx) about Razor views and layouts.

Comment: thank you. Glad I asked. Wow, this was an easy switch. just changed my controller and it is working. thanks a lot.

Comment: @frank, so if this post helped you solve the problem you were having you may consider [marking it as answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the tick next to it.

Comment: Just to be clear to those searching and ending up here, there is a distinction though in processing - viewstart support, layout support (as you mentioned), etc http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2014/01/is-there-really-no-difference-between.html

Comment: Nice.. clean and simple explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio doesn't determine which is a view and which is a partial view.  You do.  You tell MVC to render a partial view, and it renders whatever you give it.